# No. of ordered pairs satisfying this equation involving G.I.F

Tags: functions

We are required to find the no. of ordered pairs $(x,y)$ satisfying the equation

$13+12[tan^{-1}x]=24[ln x]+8[e^x]+6[cos^{-1}y]$. ($[.]$ is the Greatest integer function, e.g.$[2.3]=2, [5.6]=5, [-1.6]=[-2]$ etc)

The answer happens to be zero. I tried to arrange the terms so that I can show that the ranges on either side of the equation don't overlap, but the logarithmic and exponential terms always make the range the set of real numbers, so that doesn't work. Also, the constraint on the domain is that $x$ must be positive because of the logarithm term. I then tried to study two cases  $x>1$ and then $x$ between zero and one. But I haven't made any progress. Any help would be appreciated; thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the L.H.S is always odd and the R.H.S is always even, so there is no solution.

Comment: is that a sufficient answer? I mean can we not rigorously 'show' that there are no solutions?

Comment: What's the problem in this answer?

Comment: No I don't say that there is a problem; I haven't heard about no solutions if one side is even and other is odd; so I thought there was maybe a more ranges-based answer. Thanks anyways.

Comment: One side is *always* even and other is *always* odd, the word '*always*' is what matters here. An even number can never be equal to an odd one.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nikunj ...but I'd still like to look at a rigorous solution...